# remove part of string - regex

Tags: regex, r

I want to remove the -5p part of my data below:

`[1] mmu-miR-322-5p  mmu-miR-10b-5p  mmu-miR-10a-5p`

I tries this `gsub(".-5p","",data)` but then it took away more than the 5p

Comment: `gsub("-5p$", "", data)#[1] "mmu-miR-322" "mmu-miR-10b" "mmu-miR-10a"`

Comment: is this `[1] mmu-miR-322-5p mmu-miR-10b-5p mmu-miR-10a-5p` a real string or the vector?

Comment: "it took away more" -- 1 character more, because of the `.` "match anything" wildcard? (If so, why did you include it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` would match the preceding character also. ie, your regex `.-5p` would match `2-5p`,`b-5p`, `a-5p` in the input vector. Because the string `-5p` is located at the last, you could use end of the line anchor `$` after `-5p`. Note that it would remove only the `-5p` present at the last. If it's present at the middle or at  first, then it won't do anything.

```
sub("-5p$","",data)
```

Example:

```
> s <- c("mmu-miR-322-5p", "mmu-miR-10b-5p", "mmu-miR-10a-5p")
> s
[1] "mmu-miR-322-5p" "mmu-miR-10b-5p" "mmu-miR-10a-5p"
> sub("-5p$","", s)
[1] "mmu-miR-322" "mmu-miR-10b" "mmu-miR-10a"
```

Comment: How do you specify "or" in gsub. example: remove 5p "or" 3p

Comment: `sub('-[35]p', '', x)`

Comment: if this present at the last use, `sub('-[35]p$', '', x)`

Comment: The anchor is honestly not neccessary if only one occurrence of these substrings are in the vector element.

Comment: it's required if he wants to remove `-3p` or `-5p` present at the last where the input contains more than one `-5p` or `-3p`

Comment: Yes if it contains more than one.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression implementation the dot `.` is a metacharacter with special meaning. Alone, it will match any single character except a newline sequence, hence the reason it removes an extra character as expected.

Since you have one occurrence of `-5p` in each of your vector elements, `sub` is all that you need here.

```
> x <- c('mmu-miR-322-5p', 'mmu-miR-10b-5p', 'mmu-miR-10a-5p')
> sub('-5p', '', x)
# [1] "mmu-miR-322" "mmu-miR-10b" "mmu-miR-10a"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use substitute operator in perl one liner and remove -5p in all the cases from the input file using slurping:

**Perl One liner Code:**

```
perl -0777 -lne "if($_ =~ s/-5p//isg) { print $_;} else { print $_;}" InputFile
```

Comment: it's R. You need to include some codes related to the language R.