# R: Remove Zero's at end of alphanumeric string

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove all zeros at the end of an alphanumeric string.

```
dd<-data.frame(a = c("11234000", "000aa456000", "a2340", "00aa45000900"))
```

Should result in:

```
dd<-data.frame(a = c("11234", "000aa456", "a234", "00aa450009"))
```

Comment: Seems to me that you should have been able to figure this out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084963/remove-part-of-string-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dd<-data.frame(a = c("11234000", "000aa456000", "a2340", "00aa45000900"))
dd$a = gsub('0+$', '', dd$a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. `$` to match the end of string and `0*` to match multiple zeros.

```
sub("0*$", "", dd$a)
# [1] "11234"      "000aa456"   "a234"       "00aa450009"
```